# How to call a Process from a JavaScript Expression - Oracle Apex v21.1

Tags: javascript, oracle, process, oracle-apex, dml

I have a form that allow the users to import a file (BLOB), put a comment and a date.

I had to create a validation function, to check if the fields are empty, here's why :

The default validation returns "undefined" when the file browser is empty, and the validation text is not translated when it is a date picker, even though i translated the message in my shared components :

[image: validation not working]

1. So, I decided to create a **Dynamic Action** with a JavaScript Expression to check the fields and display errors.

```js
apex.message.clearErrors();

var chkErr = 0;
//declare fields
var arr = [
   'P28_BLOB_DOCUMENT', 
   'P28_COMMENTAIRE_DOCUMENT',
   'P28_DATE_DOCUMENT'
];
//declare Labels
var arrLabel = [
    "Importer un document",
    "Commentaire",
    "Date d'exportation"
];

//Check NULL
for (var i in arr) {
  if ($v(arr[i]).length == 0) {
    apex.message.showErrors([
      {
        type: apex.message.TYPE.ERROR,
        location: ["inline", "page"],
        pageItem: arr[i],
        message: arrLabel[i] + " doit contenir une valeur",
        unsafe: false
      }
    ]);
    chkErr = 1;
  } 
}

if ( chkErr == 0 ) { 
  /* Custom dynamic action call when no error occurred */
  apex.message.confirm("Do you want to import this document ?", function(okPressed) {
    if (okPressed) {

        apex.submit({request:'insertDocumentProcess'});
        //apex.submit('insertDocumentProcess');

    }
    });
}
```

Everythings works, if I add this DA to my button, I have my validations :

[image: validations working]

Now here comes the real problem, if I use the Dynamic Action on the `CREATE` button, the auto process "Form - Automatic Row Processing (DML)", is not executing anymore. Even tough I tried to call it using the `apex.submit('insertDocumentProcess');` or `apex.submit({request:'insertDocumentProcess'});`, the `INSERT` action is not executing on the database.

Here are all the details :

1. The create button, with the code explained above

[image: create button]

2. The process that is generated automatically when creating the form, that I try to call

[image: the process]

Did I miss something ? The `INSERT` was working fine when I'm not adding the validation function, so is the problem related to the way I'm calling the process ? Or is it because I'm trying to INSERT a BLOB FILE and I'm missing something ?

I tried different options, with another DA calling the process, but It wasn't successful.

I still have the success message from the process at the end, saying "Row created", but it doesn't appear in the database. Could it still confirm that I'm calling successfully the process ?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `Client-side Condition` in your Dynamic Action `checkErrors`. Pick `JavaScript expression` to verify if text fields pass the validation or not

Example

```
(
 apex.item('P28_BLOB_DOCUMENT').isEmpty() ||
 apex.item('P28_COMMENTAIRE_DOCUMENT').isEmpty() ||
 apex.item('P28_DATE_DOCUMENT').isEmpty()
)
```

`True action` should be the JavaScript code that validates empty fields (code you posted above).

```
apex.message.clearErrors();

var chkErr = 0;
//declare fields
var arr = [
   'P28_BLOB_DOCUMENT', 
   'P28_COMMENTAIRE_DOCUMENT',
   'P28_DATE_DOCUMENT'
]; //this is the code you pasted above
```

`False action` should be an Action: `Submit Page` and fill the option `Request / Button Name`: `CREATE` to tell APEX that you want to `Insert` or `SAVE` if you want to `Update`, this will reproduce the same behavior of normal submit.

[image]

Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: Working perfectly ! Thanks a lot !